# NSXMLParser encoding error

Tags: ios, xml, encoding, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I'm programming an application using latin characters. Here are the lines I use to get data by XML parsing.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString]; // urlString : param of the function
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
```

But for example, **œ** or **'** are replaced by **¿**. So what should I do ?

The encoding of my xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO8859-1"?>
```

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

**œ** ==> `&oelig;` and for  **'** ==> `&apos;`

if you need more characters use this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: for example to write **œuf**  which is egg in French: you write &oelig;uf