# How to parse SAP business connector link in iPhone using Obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xml-parsing, sap-basis

I have SAP business connector URL which opens in XML format in browser. When I paste  SAP BU URL in browser, the pop up opens with asking user ID and password. Then after entering the password it shows XML format data. I know how to parse XML file in iPhone but that method is not working with this SAP URL.

What are the steps required to fetch data from this kind of URL which have User ID & password in iPHone using xcode, objective C?

Updated with Code

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

self.myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://connect- test.com....."];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:self.myURL
                                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                    timeoutInterval:60];

[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

// Configure and show the window
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge: (NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");

NSURLCredential *newCredential;
newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"User"
                                          password:@"pwd"
                                        persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];

[[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential  forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");

}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse  *)response {
self.ZSETIK = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@  ZSETIK",ZSETIK);

}

 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
 [ZSETIK appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
[ZSETIK release];
[connection release];
// [textView setString:@"Unable to fetch data"];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
//NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://connect- test.hettich.com/invoke/ZSETIK/main? vendor=su&material=100200300&purchaseorderno=4502892791"];

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:self.ZSETIK];
//Initialize the delegate.
XMLParser *parser = [[XMLParser alloc] initXMLParser];

//Set delegate
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];

//Start parsing the XML file.
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

if(success)
    NSLog(@"No Errors");
else
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error!!!");

NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[ZSETIK
                                               length]);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use asynchronous NSURLConnection, following NSURLConnectionDelegate will get called in this case, provide username and password and you will get xml response.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

  NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");

  NSURLCredential *newCredential;
  newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"root"
             password:@"rootpassword"
             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];


  NSLog(@"credential created");

  [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

  NSLog(@"responded to authentication challenge");

}
```

Comment: My link is not getting parse though it shows byte length of DATA. What to change in above coding?

Comment: hi Navnath, can you post your code here so we can check if there is any issue, also check if you are getting data in browser may be there is some issue with server url.

Comment: I have posted some code above, do you need Parsing code to examine? My parsing methods is giving Error 81...

Comment: the code looks fine, may be you can print the xml response and check if there is any issue in it.

Comment: according to this link http://ios.forums.wordpress.org/topic/understanding-nsxmlparsererrordomain-error-messages. My code is showing NSXMLParserInvalidEncodingError. Do you have any idea about this

Comment: i didn't received such error before but as error indicates there is some invalid character encoding issue, you can check the response, also refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777859/nsxmlparser-encoding-error) question.